# Lync Server Deploy Certificate Verification Failed

Tags: certificate, lync

Just got my Lync server deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 and am trying to connect via Lync client on a different machine. When attempting to sign in, the client throws an error saying "Cannot sign in to Lync: There was a problem verifying the certificate from the server.".

Looking deeper, into the client box's event viewer, I see the following error "The certificate received from the remote serer was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate. ....

My organization has an internal CA, which is in charge of issuing all required certificates to the Lync server. My client box has installed the internal CA (root) as a trusted CA provider. To me, this should cause any certificates that issues, including the Lync certificates, to be trusted.

I installed Lync client on the same box that Lync server is hoted, and am able to log in fine. My error only occurs when connecting from a different box.

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll have more luck with this on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue.  To resolve:  from client, hit url of CA Authority, some thing like http://CAservername/certsrv this provided option to download a CA Certificate Chain.
Put this into local computer trusted root certs and I was good to go.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have a web server enabled on my internal domain controller, which is also my CA.  Is there another way to get the certificate chain?

Comment: @Nathan DeWitt Do you have any other sites or services that use this certificate chain directly? If so, you can navigate to that site or service and download the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error message ("Cannot sign in to Lync: There was a problem verifying the certificate from the server"), this is clearly a certification error. If you work in a big company (where they have they own internal CA - (Certification Authority)) in most cases they would have used their internal certificate to establish trust relationship. If you just install/export the Root certificate of the CA under "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities” of “Local Computer” account, this error should be resolved.

If your company doesn't have own CA, then find our who issued the certificate for Lynch and install/export the root certificate of that CA to the same location as above, this issue should be resolved.